# Display HK$ and MX$ on all Browsers

Tags: javascript, locale

I've been pulling my hair for hours on this issue, and I can't seem to make it uniform.

Has anyone found the correct locale property to display these currency formats?

I'm using plain javascript Number.toLocaleString if it's any help.

Here's a jsbin of what I've been testing: http://jsbin.com/pixufuwape/edit?html,css,js,console

Thanks all.